# Loop through list of items (skip and continue counting)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to count the number of list of items and make those numbers as a label of each item. But it needs to skip some specific numbers while counting. For example,

**A fixed of 10 list of items, will skip the number 3, 6, 8, 9 and 13.. then will continue counting. The result should be like this below.**

- List: 1
- List: 2
- List: 4
- List: 5
- List: 7
- List: 10
- List: 11
- List: 12
- List: 14
- List: 15

Please note that I can't use the `.append()` function because for some reason the HTML list structure is fixed and shouldn't be modified (hide, remove, append etc). The number value is only need to be labeled in each of item using `<span>`.

```js
jQuery('ul li').each(function(j){
 var j = j+1;
 if (j == 6) {
  return;
 }
 jQuery(this).find('span').html(j);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Provide your desired output.

Comment: @Arif The desired output is already provided. Please see the list of items underneath the bold texts.

Comment: check the Charles answer it meets your requirements. I added a Fiddler demo there.

Comment: @Arif please see my reply to his answer.

Comment: Can you check my own answer @lvlzero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array and the array.prototype.includes() in JS to check whether or not that number of list item is included in a 'do not use' list. In jQuery you can use .inArray() to achieve the same thing.

Here's the jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  skipCount([3, 6, 8, 9, 13], 'span');
});

function skipCount(doNotUse, identifier) {
  var counter = 1;
  var list = $(identifier);
  for (i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    if ($.inArray(counter, doNotUse)===-1) {
      $(list[i]).text(counter);
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter++;
      i--;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
 <li> List: <span></span> </li>
</ul>
```

Above you can pass any 'do not use' array and identifier into the function.

using jQuery `.text()`, instead of `.html()`, will allow you to just change the text inside the span elements, and not the HTML of the page.

And here's a basic JS version in case anyone wants that in the future:

```
function skipCount(doNotUse, list) {
  var counter = 1;
  for (i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    if (!doNotUse.includes(counter)) {
      list[i].innerHTML = counter;
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter++;
      i--;
    }
  }
}

function init() {
  elems = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
  skipCount([3, 6, 8, 9, 13], elems);
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Could you please convert it to jQuery?

Comment: Yes, see answer now for jQuery version @lvlzero

Comment: It works! it's counting the list while skipping selected numbers. Thanks for `.length`, it's still continue counting if ever i change (either decreasing or increasing) the number of list of items which is a big plus.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of numbers that you don't want to include. Then use the jquery inArray function to determine if it's in the array.  If it's in the array, then skip it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var count = 1;
   var nums = [3, 6, 8, 9, 13];
   $('ul li').each(function(){
      if($.inArray(count, nums) === -1){
         $(this).find('span').html(count);
       } else {
         $(this).hide();
       }   
       count++;
   });
 });
```

Fiddler output https://jsfiddle.net/Arif2009/qwczf634/

Comment: HTML shouldn't modified (hide, remove, append). We can't use `.hide()` function. The fixed list should be kept and will add number value to only to `span`

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, I think this code will meet your requirements:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var nums = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7,10,11,12,14,15];
   $('ul li').each(function(index){
   console.log(index);
      $(this).find('span').html(nums[index]);
   });
 });
```

Fiddler demo https://jsfiddle.net/Arif2009/qwczf634/11/

Comment: @ADuBois has give a better answer but this is accepted too since it's also solve the problem.